# Не бросает на нужный кусок кода

Tags: android, kotlin

Я не могу элементарно проверить работу своего кода и я понять не могу почему меня бросает на `onFailure`. Вот мой код:

```
    private fun initProfileStatus() {
        binding.appBarMain.onOffBtn.setOnClickListener {
            binding.appBarMain.loader.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val network: MainNetwork =
                getNetworkService()
            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            if (i == 0) {

                when {
                    !isConnected() -> {
                        builder.setTitle("Внимание!")
                        builder.setMessage("Требуется подключение к интернету")
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Ок") {dialog, i ->
                            binding.appBarMain.loader.visibility = View.GONE
                            return@setNegativeButton
                        }
                        builder.show()
                    }
                    !isLocationEnabled(this) -> {
                        builder.setTitle("Внимание!")
                        builder.setMessage("Требуется подключение к геолокации")
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Ок") {dialog, i ->
                            binding.appBarMain.loader.visibility = View.GONE
                            return@setNegativeButton
                        }

                        builder.show()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {

                            // Create JSON using JSONObject
                            val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                            jsonObject.put("status", "online")
                            jsonObject.put("track", "")
                            val jsonObjectString = jsonObject.toString()
                            val requestBody = jsonObjectString.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())

                            kotlin.runCatching {
                                user = network.setProfileStatus(bearerToken,requestBody)
                            }.onSuccess {
                                binding.appBarMain.loader.visibility = View.GONE
                                Log.wtf("ya_user_status", user?.data?.status)
                                showStatusDialog(user?.data?.status!!)
                                i = 1
                                binding.appBarMain.createPosButton.visibility = View.GONE
                                binding.appBarMain.myRoute.visibility = View.GONE
                                binding.appBarMain.bottomSheetGrip.visibility = View.GONE
                                binding.appBarMain.createSupplyButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                binding.appBarMain.onOffBtn.background.setTint(Color.GREEN)
                                binding.appBarMain.animationOnline.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                isOnline = true
                                startTrackingLocation()
                            }.onFailure {
                                binding.appBarMain.loader.visibility = View.GONE
                                Log.wtf("ya_user_status", " something wrong")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                    stopTrackingLocation()

                    // Create JSON using JSONObject
                    val jsonObject = JSONObject()
                    jsonObject.put("status", "offline")
                    jsonObject.put("track", SystemUtils.track)
                    val jsonObjectString = jsonObject.toString()
                    val requestBody = jsonObjectString.toRequestBody("application/json".toMediaTypeOrNull())

                    kotlin.runCatching {
                        user = network.setProfileStatus(bearerToken,requestBody)
                    }.onSuccess {
                        binding.appBarMain.createPosButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        binding.appBarMain.myRoute.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.appBarMain.bottomSheetGrip.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.appBarMain.createSupplyButton.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.appBarMain.loader.visibility = View.GONE
                        binding.appBarMain.onOffBtn.background.setTint(Color.RED)
                        binding.appBarMain.animationOnline.visibility = View.GONE
                        isOnline = false
                        Log.wtf("ya_user_status", user?.data?.status)
                        showStatusDialog(user?.data?.status!!)
                        i = 0
                        SystemUtils.track = ""
                    }.onFailure {
                        binding.appBarMain.loader.visibility = View.GONE
                        Log.wtf("ya_user_status", " something wrong")
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

В логах мне выводит something wrong при нажатии на кнопку

Comment: выводит то что вы сказали выводить, попробуйте сделать более удобоваримый вывод, чтобы ошибки показывало

Comment: В том-то и дело, что оно должно идти в onSuccess и выводить user?.data?.status

Comment: у вас слушатель  binding.appBarMain.onOffBtn.setOnClickListener находится внутри метода initProfileStatus. где вызывается метод initProfileStatus ??

Comment: Wlad, он вызывается сразу после старта

Comment: Чтобы не гадать, выведите в лог ошибку следующим образом: `.onFailure { error -> Log.wtf("ya_user_status", "something wrong", error) }`. И [приложите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1306999/edit) полученный стектрейс в ваш вопрос.